# Doble sentido y significado regional de "ignorante"

Tags: hispanoamérica

En la Wikipedia encontré algo que me sorprendió hasta el punto de molestarme (no porque quiera fingir que los insultos no existen, sino porque me parece que lo que está escrito no es verosímil). En la sección de [derogativos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_profanity#Racial_and_ethnic_derogatives), encontré:

> **Ignorante** outdated offense used by Chileans, Colombians, Mexicans and Paraguayans to describe Argentines.

Si esto es cierto, ¿tiene alguien evidencia? (En la misma fuente se encuentra *The word "argentino" (Argentine) is an anagram for "ignorante" (ignorant) in Spanish.*, que no me parece que tenga ninguna conexión con afirmación anterior)

Answer (score 3):

Me llamó mucho la atención la pregunta porque conozco una pequeña obra de arte que se le atribuye a [Nicanor Parra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicanor_Parra) que menciona el anagrama:

[image: Nicanor Parra: Artefactos]

Adicionalmente lo encontré mencionado en [varios libros](https://www.google.cl/search?q=argentino%20anagrama%20de%20ignorante&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjirI3qq-PvAhVnD7kGHT58AzQQpwUIJQ&biw=1649&bih=964&dpr=2) (no he podido ver el contenido pero hay algunos bastante antiguos) y en la siguiente publicación más o menos reputable:

https://www.diarioelargentino.com.ar/opinion/buen-dia/4469

Es particularmente interesante que la frase se le atribuye a [Augusto Belín Sarmiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augusto_Bel%C3%ADn_Sarmiento), o a su abuelo materno, [Domingo Faustino Sarmiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domingo_Faustino_Sarmiento), quien de alguna forma recibe un retruque en la mencionada obra de Parra.